# Отправка сообщений Telegram bot

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Для написания бота, я использую библиотеку для java [TelegraBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots)

Когда Java-класс `extends TelegramLongPollingBot`, то я могу добавить метод отправки сообщения на сервер (в том же классе):

```
private void sendAllMessages(String chatId, String text) {
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.setText(text);
        message.setChatId(chatId);
        try {
            execute(message);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Но мне не хочется вызывать весь класс в другом классе ради одного метода. Я хотел бы вынести возможность отправки сообщений в отдельный класс. Как это лучше всего стоит сделать?

Примерно как я это вижу:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class sendMessages {

    private String chatId, text;
    public sendMessages(String chatId, String text){
        this.chatId = text;
        this.text = text;
    }

    private void sendAllMessages() {
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.setText(text);
        message.setChatId(chatId);
        try {
            execute(message);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sendMessages` в его конструкторе отпечатка.

Comment: то что есть и то что вы сделали, по ситу одно и тоже

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov пример кода - это грубое представление того, как я вижу программу. Перечитайте, пожалуйста, мой вопрос. P.S. В конструкторе нет опечатки

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov уже все. Ответ нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил. Я решил пойти на хитрый шаг:

У Вас есть файл, допустим, `EventHandler.java` в котором `public class EventListener extends TelegramLongPollingBot{...}`.

Создаем второй класс, допустим, `SendMessagesBot`.
В нем создаем метод:

```
public void sendEvent(String chatId, String text){
    SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
    message.setText(text);
    message.setParseMode(ParseMode.MARKDOWN);
    message.setChatId(Long.parseLong(chatId));
    try {
        //просто вызываем класс EventListner с методом execute
        new EventListener().execute(message);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```